# How to get a list of stored procedure along with their execution count in oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-12c

Hi I am new to Oracle 12c, though I was working on SQL Server for a long time.

Is there a way to get a list of stored procedures with their execution count in oracle 12c.

We can get it using DMV in SQL Server (various versions). But I am looking for it in Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list them with this query (similar to **sys.procedures**):

```
SELECT * FROM USER_PROCEDURES
```

For execution count, I think you will have to use Audit functionnalities.